# what does this php expression regarding session variables mean?

Tags: php

What does isset($_SESSION) mean? I found the following code snippet-

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {

// php code

}
```

EDIT:

I found the following snippet in define.php of the facebook style chatting script 
[freichat](http://evnix.com/drupal2/) :

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
            $this->frm_id = $_SESSION[$this->uid . 'usr_ses_id'];
            $this->frm_name = $_SESSION[$this->uid . 'usr_name'];
        }
```

if $_SESSION was not set previously then, how can the two session variables be assigned to other variables?

Comment: the obvious explanation is that it checks if $_SESSION does not exist, which you could have found out easily by looking up `isset` in the PHP manual. Unless you clarify what you are having trouble to understand, I'd argue this is not a real question.

Comment: This is check for session started.

Comment: i know what isset means. isset($_SESSION['somename']) is quite clear to me .But what does isset($_SERVER) mean? I did not find the answer in net. Does it aim to check whether even a single session variable exists throughout the site? Still I am going to add comments to the reply I got to make the thing clear to me.

Comment: `isset($_SESSION)` checks whether the superglobal `$_SESSION` exists, which it won't when the session wasnt started yet.

Comment: I got it. this kind if code is less used i think

Comment: as of PHP 5.4 you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php to check whether session is enabled or not. before that you can check whether session_id() returns an empty string.

Comment: if session not enabled then the if condition in the edited part holds true. my question is still valid

Comment: it cant: http://codepad.viper-7.com/pRf7cZ

Comment: @Gordon, i saw the codepad.  That shows undefined variable. my question is also at that point. suppose session_start() not used before. then if (!isset($_SESSION)) will return true and the code within { .. } will execute. But if session_start() was not used, then how can $_SESSION[$this->uid . 'usr_ses_id']; hold any value? I am trying to make my point clear

Comment: added answer summarizing my points from above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary from my comments:

- `isset` [determines if a variable is set and is not NULL](http://php.net/isset).
- Putting an `!` [negates the condition](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php), so `if (!false)` will evaluate to true.
- `$_SESSION` is a superglobal and will be available on the [following conditions](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php):

> Please note when working with sessions that a record of a session is not created until a variable has been registered using the `session_register()` function or by adding a new key to the `$_SESSION` superglobal array. This holds true regardless of if a session has been started using the `session_start()` function.

Your `if (!isset($_SESSION))` will evaluate to true when no Session exists yet. It will then execute the code in the if block. However, that code will not work. If you [run this snippet](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Kx2RMF)

```
<?php
var_dump($_SESSION);                // undefined notice + NULL
var_dump(isset($_SESSION));         // FALSE
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {            // !FALSE is TRUE
    $foo = $_SESSION['usr_ses_id']; // undefined notice
}
var_dump($foo);                     // NULL
var_dump($_SESSION);                // still undefined undefined + NULL
```

you will see that it outputs:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in /code/Kx2RMF on line 2
NULL 
bool(false)
Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in /code/Kx2RMF on line 5
NULL
Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in /code/Kx2RMF on line 8
NULL
```

So unless I am missing something, I'd say the code in that chat script makes no sense.

Comment: ' I'd say the code in that chat script makes no sense.' - that is the point that makes me confused. I cannot understand whay that code snippet was necessary to be in the script. ok i'll ask them and .on getting any answer, will share that here

Answer (score 2):

It means if session (`$_SESSION` is array, a built-in variable for PHP) is NOT set (designated with `!`). That basically checks if there are no active session vars/array, do something / run php code in that condition.

Though correct way is to usually check for specific session variable something like:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['key name'])) { ... }
```

See docs for further info:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed: Gordon has replied that in his comment above :)

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed: The code in your edit means. If `$_SESSION` array IS NOT SET which means it is empty, the if condition in your edit's code sets new session variables eg `$_SESSION[$this->uid . 'usr_ses_id']` and `$_SESSION[$this->uid . 'usr_name']`

Comment: so, if session was started but not a single session variable was declared in any of the pages, then the if condition would return true. right?

Comment: ' IS NOT SET which means it is empty, ' - i think it would be clearer to say that isset($_SESSION) checks whether session_start was used previously. In that case my question in the edited part is still unsolved i think

Answer (score 0):

It's checking to see if any session variables have been set.  In PHP, `$_SESSION` is an array of values, so without specifying the `[]` operator, it's checking to see if `$_SESSION` has ever been set.

Answer (score 0):

It means the session wasn't initialized yet and you should call `session_start()`before trying to use any session features.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php